# "current" class on menu

Tags: php, html, kohana

Heya, I'm creating a menu and was wondering if how i would add a class of "current" on a menu for the current page e.g. http://emberapp.com/. Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just tell the view which slug is active, and do

```
<li<?php echo ($activeSlug === $thisSlug) ? ' class="active"' : NULL; ?>></li>
```

Answer (score 1):

Also look at [Request::$uri](http://kohanaframework.org/guide/api/Request#property:uri) which you can access using `Request::instance()->uri`:

```
if (Request::instance()->uri === $link) $active = TRUE;
```